# Creating a MongoDB database through the defined classes / documents in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to be able to use my Entities classes / documents created with Java Spring in order to create my MongoDB Database at Runtime abd see the different fields of the documents and collections and this automatically when running my spring boot application.
I use the property in my `application.properties`.

```
hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database=true
```

and as a dependency in `pom.xml` :

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

The application launches but the associated database is not created, What am i missing here,

Thank you.

Comment: Is the rest of your application setup properly? Do you have MongoDb up and running? Need more info. I think at the very least is does spring currently connect to a running MongoDb instance?

Comment: To work with MongoDB database data you can use the Spring Data MongoDB APIs _or_ MongoDB Java Driver APIs (from a Spring Boot application). See this Spring documentation: [Using Repositories with Multiple Spring Data Modules](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.multiple-modules).

Comment: Did you set up the persistence provider? If you are using a persitence.xml you need to add <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider> like in the example: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/#ogm-gettingstarted

Comment: i need one example

Comment: @Davide no no persitence.xml just pom.xml

Comment: @Tony Yes it is set properly

Comment: Does this help (Example 7)? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/#_accessing_the_code_ogmsession_code_api

Comment: There is no support in Spring Data for Hibernate OGM. You can use Spring Data JPA, Spring Data Mongodb or Hibernate OGM. It seems you have them all mixed up currently and it isn't even clear which one you want to use.